# viewDidAppear running, and then not running.

Tags: ios

In my ios app, I begin by loading the SecondViewController using the code shown below.  When that view controller appears, I also run viewDidAppear as shown in the code snippet below. 
That works ok.  From there, I load my FifthViewController and do some calculating which needs to be returned to the SecondViewController.
Unfortunately, when I return to SecondViewController via the same exact method, the viewDidAppear method does not run. 
Any suggestions on how to fix that would be appreciated.

```
-(IBAction) loadSecondView:(id)sender
{


NSLog(@"In loadSecondView method \n");

[secondViewController viewDidAppear:YES];

[self clearView];
[self.view insertSubview:secondViewController.view atIndex:1];

}
```

Comment: `viewDidAppear:` is *not* a method that you are supposed to call yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something to be performed every time after dismissing a viewcontroller, you should use delegate method. It is much more specific than viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.

Here's a [website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) where you can get started.

Comment: I am reading up on that subject.  I wonder, if viewDidAppear isn't firing, how would a delegate method make it happen?

Comment: The delegate method is called directly by the closing viewcontroller. That's why its guaranteed to be fired if you program it correctly.

Comment: I added a link where you can see how delegate method is used.