# Modifying static cells outside cellForRowAtIndexPath without creating new cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So I get that its typically frowned upon to modify a cell outside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath but here is what I have:

I have a static table that is used as an index of questions (1-33).  Each row has a question on it and a detail disclosure indicator. All of this is manually entered in on the stoyboard.

I have a file that lists each question and some properties such as if the question has been answered.
When this screen loads (viewDidAppear) I want to check if each of these questions have been loaded and if so switch the detail indicator to a checkmark.

Now this works, for the first 5 cells.  If I go to a question and come back, then even more cells are checked (even if the questions have not been answered).  Is this undefined behavior because I am accessing it outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Here is the code I'm using to access and change the cell:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (question1Answered)
    { 
        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:3]];
        [cell1 setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
}
```

Again, it does work for the first 5 elements, then the rest will not change no matter what I do. Then if I go to a question and return it shows more with it selected.  Strange behavior...

**EDIT:** I just noticed that the above code works but it only updates the cells that are currently on the screen.  So if I scroll down, leave and come back all the visible cells will have the check mark. Is there a way to force a refresh of all the cells, even if they aren't visible?

Thanks for any and all help...

-David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to another question I answered few days ago. See [stackoverflow.com/a/11770387/1479411](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770387/1479411)

Use delegate method. Put any code that modifies the cell content and [self.tableView reloadData] in the delegate method after returning from the other view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should not update cell from `viewDidAppear`.

Instead you should reload data from viewDidApeear.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (question1Answered)
    {             
        //This will call your tableview's delegate for visible cells
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

And inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, you should take a decision to assign accessory type.

Answer (score 0):

U should first update your model then update your UI according to the model state.
For example if your model is an array of `Question` object, and each question has some `hasBeenAnswered` boolean.
Then the only thing u should do in viewDidAppear is to call `[self.tableView reloadData]`, this will update your table view because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called and set the cells according to your model state.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // configure the cell according to your model state  
    Question *question = [self.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

    // check if this question has been answered
    if (question.hasBeenAnswered) {
       // if yes - set a checkmark
       [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];  
    }
    else {
       // if not - set to none (or whatever u want)
       [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    return cell;
}
```